# Cómo puedo posicionar botones en cualquier parte de mi pantalla

Tags: html

¿Cómo puedo posicionar  botones en cualquier  parte de mi pantalla, aumentarles el tamaño  y posicionar un botón debajo del otro?

Es decir, con cuáles funciones o propiedades puedo desplazarlos y aumentar su tamaño, ya que busco colocarlos en la parte central de mi pantalla debajo de una cabecera que ya tengo diseñada.

```html
<button type="button" name="btnprueba">Prueba</button>
<button type="button" name="btnmenu1">Menu</button>
```

Comment: Hola @rolyx22, aunque esta pregunta es interesante y se ajusta a la temática del sitio, tal y como está redactada es demasiado amplia. Deberías añadir una mejor descripción de lo que quieres conseguir (quizás con una imagen esquematizando cómo quieres que se vea) y también añadir algo más de código (lo que llevas hasta ahora y lo que hayas intentado). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: También sería bueno que aclarases si buscas una solución con CSS o si lo que quieres es algo con JavaScript. Dependiendo de cómo o cuándo quieras hacer esos desplazamientos o cambios de tamaño, puede ser un punto importante a tener en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Para alinear puedes hacerlo dentro de los  con la propieda align, aca te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
<button type="button" name="btnprueba">Prueba</button>
<button type="button" name="btnmenu1">Menu</button>
</div>
```

Comment: El atributo `align` (tal y como está en este ejemplo) se considera obsoleto y no debería utilizarse más. En su lugar, debería optarse por soluciones basadas en CSS (como por ejemplo `text-align`, grid o flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

al parecer creo que te refieres a las propiedades HTML, Button no tiene una propiedad HTML para eso, pero puedes utilizar CSS, de la siguiente manera

```
<button style="height:200px; width:200px"></button>
```

Recuerda height la altura y width el ancho, el tamaño lo das en pixeles.

Ahora para ubicar tus botones puedes utilizar DIVS

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button style="position: absolute;top: 50%;">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Te recomiendo que visites la pagina https://www.w3schools.com y tomes unas lecciones de CSS
Buena suerte!!!